# Using indexOf to search the document.referrer for a home domain and act upon this

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to add an on-page "back" link that will only appear if the referrer was the home domain.

I have been through a number of threads on here which have been very helpful, but my code does not work despite being a combination of others' supposedly working code.  I am at a loss as to why:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('MyDomain') > -1) {
    document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">&lt;&lt;Back to Results</a>');
}
```

When the referrer is on my domain it works as intended, but when the referrer is not on my domain it still writes the link.

Comment: What is the value of `document.referrer`?

Comment: I see you're a new member of Stack Overflow, please be aware of just how active SO is - when you ask a question it's worth hanging around to see if there are any follow up comments such as Quentin's above, as a question will typically have a  fair amount of views almost immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your advice re regular checking.

Comment: In answer to Quentin's question, the value of document.referrer;

Comment: In answer to Quentin's question, the value of document.referrer;
If the previous page is on my domain: http://**mydomain.co/apage.aspx
if coming from a different domain: http://**www.otherdomain.co/apage.html

Without the asterisks of course.

Is your point that the target string would need to be at the start of the searched string?  i.e. that i need to avoid the HTTP?